# Writing into date fields with Cypress

Tags: angular, date, testing, cypress, devextreme

I am writing e2e tests for web application with Cypress. I have a problem with writing values in the date fields. Date fields were created using DevExtreme. Exactly, I must use indexes to access these fields. I am trying to avoid this. Because, if developer adds new date field, the indexes will be changed. I tried to use name property, but input is shown as hidden and my test always fails.

I was exploring about this problem and found out that it can be solved with DxClick trigger. I couldn't find any examples how to do this with Cypress.

Does anyone have any examples of using this trigger with Cypress?

Comment: I tried with: cy.trigger('dxclick'), but I got the error: Timed out retrying: cy.trigger() failed because this element is not visible.

Comment: Example:

it('should enter the start date', function() {
        
        cy 

            .get('input')
            .eq(18)
            .trigger('dxclick')
            .wait(3000)
            .type(this.admin.date)
            .should("have.value", this.admin.date)
            .wait(3000);
    })

Comment: I am trying to avoid indexes. That means, I don't want to use .eq(18) to access this field. This element has input type hidden. Also, the name property name is set on this element, but I can't access this field using name property. Does exist an way in dev extreme to access date field with Cypress?